# Gaps - how to show values with a specific symbol?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with numbers - 1,2,3...100. 5 of them looks like 1_, 3_, 5_
So, actually I have 1, 1_, 2, 3, 3_, 4, 5, 5_, 6, 7, 8 ...
I did the query:

```
SELECT code
FROM table.column1
WHERE column1 LIKE '%_'
```

to get the list of this numbers with _. Instesd of it I got the list of all values, including values with _. What's your opinion - what's the reason, where is a mistake?

Comment: `_` is the wildcard for a single character in `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

The character `_` is, similar to `%`, a wildcard in `LIKE`-operations. While `%` matches multiple characters, `_` only matches a single character. To get your expected result you need to escape the `_` character:

```sql
SELECT code
FROM table.column1
WHERE column1 LIKE '%\_'
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gy1f7kCrX1xbFCQvzevj28/0) showing it.

Answer (score 0):

You use the "E" before the string to escape the symbol.

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1
WHERE col1 LIKE E'%\_';
```